# Derivative of trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

$$\dfrac{\partial\operatorname{Trace}\left[\left(AB\right)^{T}Q\left(AB\right)\right]}{\partial A}=\text{ ?}$$

where $Q = Q^T>0$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: Have you tried writing everything out using indices and summations? For an example, I used this in an answer on another [matrix derivative question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466420/derivative-of-xtax2/).

Comment: Is $Q$ independent of $A$?

Comment: You can see the [matrix cookbook](http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf).

Comment: Really, I know it's short, but I'd vote up anyone who offers the Matrix Cookbook to any relevant question. It's a gem!

Answer (score 2):

It is easy. The derivative in $A$ is $Df(A):H\rightarrow 2Trace(((AB)^TQHB)=2Trace(B(AB)^TQH)=2(QABB^T.H)$ where $.$ is the scalar product over the real matrices $(U,V)\rightarrow (U.V)=Trace(U^TV)$. Consequently, the gradient of $f$ in $A$ is $\nabla(f)(A)=2QABB^T$.